# Resample Sentinel-2 bands from 20m to 10m using GEE code outside of GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-python-api, resampling

I want to resample the 20 meters bands of Sentinel-2 to 10 meters. I found this piece of code in GEE and after trying it out, this is what I would like to do to my Sentinel images but outside of GEE.
I'm having a hard time on what is the best way to do this in Python.

How can I do this?

```py
def calculateOutput(bandName,stdDev20m,stdDevHighPassFilter,image20mResampled,highPassFilter,modulatingFactor=0.25):
  bandName = ee.String(bandName)
  W = ee.Image().expression('stdDev20m / stdDevHighPassFilter * modulatingFactor',{
      'stdDev20m': stdDev20m.select(bandName),
      'stdDevHighPassFilter': stdDevHighPassFilter,
      'modulatingFactor': 0.25
  })
  im = ee.Image().expression('image20mResampled + (HPF * W)',{
      'image20mResampled': image20mResampled.select(bandName),
      'HPF': highPassFilter,
      'W': W    
  }).uint16()
  return im

def upscaling(params):
  if params and not isinstance(params['image'], ee.Image):
    raise ValueError('pansharpening: You must provide an params object with an image key.')
  image = params['image']
  geometry = params['geometry']
  crs = image.select(0).projection().crs()
  maxPixels = params['maxPixels']
  bestEffort = params['bestEffort'] or False
  tileScale =   1

  image = image.clip(geometry)
  bands10m = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8']
  bands20m = ['B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12']

  panchromatic = image.select(bands10m).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
  image20m = image.select(bands20m)
  image20mResampled = image20m.resample('bilinear')

  stats20m = image20m.reduceRegion(
      reducer =  ee.Reducer.stdDev().combine(
        ee.Reducer.mean(), None, True
      ),
      geometry = geometry,
      scale = 20,
      crs = crs, 
      bestEffort = bestEffort, 
      maxPixels = maxPixels, 
      tileScale = tileScale).toImage()

  mean20m = stats20m.select('.*_mean').regexpRename('(.*)_mean', '$1')
  stdDev20m = stats20m.select('.*_stdDev').regexpRename('(.*)_stdDev', '$1')

  kernel = ee.Kernel.fixed(
    width=5,
    height=5,
    weights=[[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
             [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
             [-1, -1, 24, -1, -1],
             [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
             [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]],
    x=-3,
    y=-3,
    normalize=False)
  highPassFilter = panchromatic.convolve(kernel).rename('highPassFilter')
  stdDevHighPassFilter = highPassFilter.reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
                                                     geometry =geometry,scale = 10,
                                                     crs = crs,bestEffort = bestEffort,
                                                     maxPixels = maxPixels,tileScale =tileScale).getNumber('highPassFilter')
  output = ee.ImageCollection([calculateOutput(b,stdDev20m,stdDevHighPassFilter,image20mResampled,highPassFilter) for b in bands20m]).toBands().regexpRename('.*_(.*)', '$1')
  statsOutput = output.reduceRegion(
      reducer = ee.Reducer.stdDev().combine(ee.Reducer.mean(),None,True),
      geometry = geometry,
      scale =10,
      crs =crs,
      bestEffort =bestEffort,
      maxPixels =maxPixels,
      tileScale =tileScale).toImage()

  meanOutput = statsOutput.select('.*_mean').regexpRename('(.*)_mean', '$1')
  stdDevOutput = statsOutput.select('.*_stdDev').regexpRename('(.*)_stdDev', '$1')
  sharpened = ee.Image().expression('(output - meanOutput) / stdDevOutput * stdDev20m + mean20m',{
      'output' : output,
      'meanOutput' : meanOutput,
      'stdDevOutput' : stdDevOutput,
      'stdDev20m' : stdDev20m,
      'mean20m' : mean20m
  }).uint16()

  return image.addBands(sharpened,None,True).select(image.bandNames())
```

I have this at the moment. However I'm not sure how to create the `calculateOutput` function and the continue the rest.

```py
def upscaling20to10m(input_folder,bands10,bands20,output_folder):
   
    band_files = os.listdir(input_folder)
    band_files = [band for band in band_files if band.endswith('.jp2')]
    path_10m = filter_strings_with_substrings(band_files,bands10)
    path_20m = filter_strings_with_substrings(band_files,bands20)

    b10m_path = []
    b20m_path = []
    for b in path_10m:
        b10m_path.append(os.path.join(input_folder,b))

    for b in path_20m:
        b20m_path.append(os.path.join(input_folder,b))
 # get bands of 10m and get mean
    panchromatic_band = np.mean([rasterio.open(os.path.join(input_folder, f)).read(1) for f in band_files if any(b in f for b in bands10) and f.endswith('.jp2')], axis=0)
    
    #read the 20m and resample using the bilinear interpolation
    image20m_resampled = np.stack([rasterio.open(os.path.join(input_folder, f)).read(1, out_shape=(panchromatic_band.shape[0], panchromatic_band.shape[1]), resampling=rasterio.enums.Resampling.bilinear) for f in band_files if any(b in f for b in bands20) and f.endswith('.jp2')], axis=0)

    #calculate std and mean for the 20m
    stats20m = np.std(image20m_resampled, axis=0), np.mean(image20m_resampled, axis=0)
    std_dev20m, mean20m = stats20m
    
    #define kernel 5x5
    kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                       [-1, -1, 24, -1, -1],
                       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])
    
    #apply high pass filter and the convolution to the panchromatic band
    high_pass_filter = convolve(panchromatic_band, kernel)
    #get the std of the high pass filter
    std_dev_high_pass_filter = np.std(high_pass_filter)
```